# install.packages("methods") failed for R 3.0.1

Tags: r, rhadoop

I try to install R package "methods" over R 3.0.1:

```
> install.packages("methods")
> Warning message:
package ‘methods’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

Is there any way to install 'methods' over R 3.0.1 or should I switch to R 3.0.0?

Thank you

Comment: You should switch to R 3.0.2. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`methods` is part of base R, you don't have to install it with `install.packages`, as it is already bundled with your R 3.0.1 installation.

You will see that loading the package will not provide any error :

```
library(methods)
```

But you don't even have to do that, as it is already loaded by default in your R session.

Answer (score 5):

**methods** is a *base package*, along with the following packages

- base
- compiler
- datasets
- graphics
- grDevices
- grid
- methods
- parallel
- splines
- stats
- stats4
- tcltk

None of these packages are on CRAN, they only exist as part of base R.
See also the [R FAQ Section 5.1.1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Which-add_002don-packages-exist-for-R_003f).